# how can i write a function in javascript to get data categorywise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render products categorywise but unable to do. how can i write a function in javascript to get data category wise? specially in react or pure javascript?

```
{
  electronics: [
    {
      id: "e-1",
      title: "Macbook Pro",
      price: "2000",
      image:
        "https://images.macrumors.com/t/uGZEsAiPbvD0wqiL5m6lE9b-Ixw=/2344x/https://images.macrumors.com/article-new/2021/01/Flat-2021-MacBook-Pro-Mockup-Feature-1.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: "e-2",
      title: "Google Pixel",
      price: "500",
      image:
        "https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2018/smartphones/org/2019-10-15-product.jpg",
    },
    
  ],
  cloths: [
    {
      id: "c-1",
      title: "Blazer cover coat",
      price: "200",
      image:
        "https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/10d33049b5e6188ff44dc9011971cf56.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp",
    },
    {
      id: "c-2",
      title: "Stylish jacket for men",
      price: "500",
      image:
        "https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/4abccdabadc9f089c4f59be2dfda2ce6.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp",
    },
   
  ],
  
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you got so far ?

Comment: are you meant electronics and cloths as category right?

Comment: Please show us the results you want.

Comment: Please add some more details like what you've tried and what you want (end) result.

Comment: ```
I want it like:
```
[
{
category:cloths,
data:[{},{}]
},
category:electronics,
data:[{},{}]
}
]
````

Comment: @SyedSakib, check out my new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Find complete React demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-liskov-wfskf?file=/src/App.tsx).

**Final Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A sample in pure JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Products list.</p>
<p id="list"></p>

<script>
var myObj, x;
myObj = {
  electronics: [
    {
      id: "e-1",
      title: "Macbook Pro",
      price: "2000",
      image:
        "https://images.macrumors.com/t/uGZEsAiPbvD0wqiL5m6lE9b-Ixw=/2344x/https://images.macrumors.com/article-new/2021/01/Flat-2021-MacBook-Pro-Mockup-Feature-1.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: "e-2",
      title: "Google Pixel",
      price: "500",
      image:
        "https://static.techspot.com/images/products/2018/smartphones/org/2019-10-15-product.jpg",
    },
    
  ],
  cloths: [
    {
      id: "c-1",
      title: "Blazer cover coat",
      price: "200",
      image:
        "https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/mdc/10d33049b5e6188ff44dc9011971cf56.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp",
    },
    {
      id: "c-2",
      title: "Stylish jacket for men",
      price: "500",
      image:
        "https://static-01.daraz.com.bd/p/4abccdabadc9f089c4f59be2dfda2ce6.jpg_340x340q80.jpg_.webp",
    },
   
  ],
  
};
for (x in myObj) {
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<p><b>" + x + "</b></p>"
  for (product in myObj[x]){
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += myObj[x][product].title + "<br>";
  }  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**The result:**

[image: javascript example, result]

Comment: @SyedSakib but you said that "react OR pure javascript". Unfortunately I don't know how to write in ReactJS.